# CountDownTimer inside AlertDialog

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a popup which is supposed to count down from 90sec to zero. I'm using the CountDownTimer method, but somewhere the an error because it doesn't do anything.
Here is the code that I have:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder popup_timer = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScoreNewGame.this);
popup_timer.setTitle("Timer:\t90 sec between games");
popup_timer.setPositiveButton("Skip", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    new CountDownTimer(90000, 1000)
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            popup_timer.setMessage("seconds remaining:\t"+millisUntilFinished);
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() 
        {
            popup_timer.setMessage("Begin next set");
        }
    }.start();
    popup_timer.show();
```

The AlertDialog only show the Title and the skip button, but no CountDownTimer, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you can change the message like that after showing. You may need to use a custom View with a `TextView` and change the text in that

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid Java. I think you are missing something between `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` and `new CountDownTimer(90000, 1000)`.